# Restore Database from latest .bak

Tags: sql-server, sql, backup

Is it possible to restore database from the latest .bak file using sql script?

Comment: Do you want to actually determine what is the last backup from a set/folder/list in the SQL script?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The basic form is:

```
RESTORE DATABASE <dbname> FROM DISK='<path to bak>';
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx for details.